# Turn template path hints off from command line

Tags: template, theme, template-hints

For whatever reason, I just did a mysqldump of our magento database, imported it into a new database, and suddenly template path hints are on, how can I turn these off from the command line? Or what table/column do I need to change in the database to turn these off?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn them off by running the following query:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '0' WHERE path LIKE '%template_hints%';
```

After running the query make sure you clean the var/cache directory too when you are in the Magento root. (`rm -rf var/cache/*`)

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 2):

alternative is using phpStorm IDE with magicento plugin, it has very usefull tools for magento development, turn on/off path hints, clean cache is also there.

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

http://magicento.com/

Comment: Good solution, but sometimes it doesn't work. Last time I'm using n98 magerun. But it can show hints only for frontend

Answer (score 1):

Switch some properties to true ;

```
class Mage_Core_Block_Template extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    ...
    //near the row 66-67
    protected static $_showTemplateHints = true;
    protected static $_showTemplateHintsBlocks = true;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Its great we can use condition here to show only using selected ip address rest can see normally.

Answer (score 1):

If out use n98-magerun2 script from https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

Run the following from website root to enable hints

```
n98-magerun2.phar dev:template-hints enable
```

And this to disable

```
n98-magerun2.phar dev:template-hints disable
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2.2 you can run the command line:

```
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable 

php bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable
```